# generate barcode at runtime using ngx-barcode

Tags: angular, barcode

I want to iterate through loop and read serials from collection and show them using ngx-barcode using the following code:

```
<tbody>
<tr *ngFor="let PS of PrintSerials">
<ngx-barcode [bc-value]="{{ PS.SerialId }}" [bc-display-value]="true"></ngx-barcode>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

but I get this error;

> NodeInvocationException: Template parse errors: Parser Error: Got
>   interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 0 in [{{
>   PS.SerialId }}] in
>   ng:///AppModuleShared/PrintSerialsComponent.html@8:25 ("   ][bc-value]="{{ PS.SerialId }}" [bc-display-value]="true"> 
>    "): ng:///AppModuleShared/PrintSerialsComponent.html@8:25

How can I show the serial barcode?
thanks

Comment: whats your PrintSerials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
<ngx-barcode [bc-value]="PS.SerialId" [bc-display-value]="true"></ngx-barcode>
```

As the error suggests, it shouldn't be using string interpolation to assign the `[bc-value]`

Comment: I already tried it but It didn't work. I mean It shows nothing.

Comment: Does `PS.SerialId` actually have a value? What errors are in the console when you apply my changes?

Comment: You are right Jamie. Actually the problem was related to the name of loop variable. I mean PS. I don't know why but when I change it to another name the serials was rendered. anyway thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

you need to remove interpolation like`[bc-value]="{{PS.SerialId}}"` to `[bc-value]="PS.SerialId"`.

Here is working example:  [ngx-barcode working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngswmp)

Hope this will help you!!!!